# When using a custom ViewGroup subclass, how do xml attributes get prioritised?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created a custom ViewGroup:

```
public class MyView extends LinearLayout {
    ...
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_view, this);
    ...
}
```

and I am using it in my `activity_main.xml` layout:

```
<mypackage.MyView android:id="@+id/my_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">
...
```

In addition, there are some attributes specified in `my_view.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
...
```

This is a bit odd, because I have the opportunity to duplicate some of the xml attributes.  My question is: how does the system decide which attributes take priority, the ones in the main layout (`activity_main.xml`) or the ones in the sublayout (`my_view.xml`)?  It seems to differ by case: if I specify a height in the main layout it appears to override the choice in the sublayout, but I cannot override the orientation in this way.